# Spring boot cannot start with aws starter dependency

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have checked on other posts but version seems to play a role and my spring boot version is

```
'2.1.8.RELEASE'
```

Spring boot does not start with the dependency
I have tried several options to get the application to start but get no success.
I only want to make use of S3 and RDS and maybe EC2.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws'
```

and the configuration of

```
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=key
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=secret

cloud.aws.region.auto=true

# Disable auto cloud formation
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
```

Keep getting the error:

```
2019-09-20 01:25:24.740  WARN 18552 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
2019-09-20 01:25:24.750  INFO 18552 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-20 01:25:24.764 ERROR 18552 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Error says it all "There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance"

Comment: Please, how can I create the EC2 metadata tho I am running it locally?

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs when you run an application locally & not on EC2,

For me excluding the below autoconfiguration worked.

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 8):

You have set the `cloud.aws.region.auto=true` parameter which enables the automatic region detection

> There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not
>   running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if
>   the application is running on a EC2 instance

See cloud aws documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/#_configuring_region)

Set it to false or remove it to avoid getting that error.

If you want to simulate the aws environment locally, the ***localstack*** project could be useful

https://github.com/localstack/localstack